# How do I make fire form if a specific splash potions lands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a splash potion that works like a Molotov in vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually quite easy to do! Just put this command in a repeating command block and power the command block when you want to activate it. `/execute at @e[type=minecraft:potion,limit=1,sort=nearest] unless block ~ ~-0.7 ~ minecraft:air run fill ~-1 ~-1 ~-1 ~1 ~1 ~1 minecraft:fire replace air`
This command will make all potions to Molotovs! That's why you should turn it off when you don't want it :)

It is more advanced if you only want a specific potion to be like a Molotov! (I don't know how to do that right now but you must do something with NBT tags!)

Comment: Ooh, interesting solution! The traditional way is to teleport an entity constantly to the potion and detect when the entity can’t teleport, but this works if it’s for the floor only.

Comment: P.S. I know how to do the NBT tag thing that you mentioned in your post. I’ll add that as an answer.

Comment: ok great and do you know how to separate different tipped arrow from each other too with nbt? i asked that before in another question but i didnt get a good answer!

Comment: the solution i have works for walls and everything else if you add all directions! like ~ ~0.7 ~,  ~-0.7 ~ ~  :)

Comment: Please link to your other question so I can see the existing answers.

Comment: i dont have another answer xD  isnt it obvious that it will works for walls if you add so it detects if not the block is air...

Comment: No, I’m asking about the way to separate tipped arrows with NBT. You said you had another question for that, could you link to it please?

Comment: weird i cant find it i most have deleted it or something idk, but you can send an example of the command here or something else.

Comment: dude this is a really cool answer! I am totally going to try out this command as soon as I get the chance